# Okular stuck on "Reloading a PDF document"

Tags: 11.10, okular

After upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and Okular seems to be not working properly. When I open a pdf document, it says 'Reloading the document ...' again and again and an hour glass is shown. The problem is intermittent and happened with the following [pdf](http://ompldr.org/vOHhwNg). Has anyone had similar experience?

Comment: can you add an example weblink to a pdf that you say produces this issue?

Comment: It happens with this [pdf](http://ompldr.org/vOHhwNg). BTW, is doesn't happen now.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is intermittent?  Don't forget to add the link info and the answer to this comment back into your question.

Comment: yes - intermittent. Will do.

Comment: sounds like a bug of some-sort.  Have you attempted to pin it down e.g. is it a size issue?  Does it occur with PDFs with form-fields etc etc.   Does this occur with "evince" or "acroread"?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your pdf and I can confirm that Okular has no problems opening it. However, there's a nice feature in Okular that makes it to reload a document whenever the file on disk is changed.

You can reproduce this by opening a terminal window and issuing

```
touch filename.pdf
```

while the same file is open in Okular. Or even

```
 while [ true ]; do touch filename.pdf; sleep 3; done
```

this will cause Okular to reload the document repeatedly.

I'm not quite sure what was "touching" the file in your case - do you have this file synced with Ubuntu One or Dropbox? Maybe some backup program?

However, the power of KDE is in the amount of knobs programs have :) If it ever bothers you again, go to Settings - Configure Okular - General and un-tick "Reload document on file change"

In you're curious, you can install `inotify-tools` package which contains command-line tools to monitor file modification messages from kernel's inotify module. You can monitor file change notifications with

```
inotifywait -m filename.pdf
```

Comment: The pdf is in DropBox, but I hardly change it.

Comment: Well, then Dropbox is my main suspect